# JavaScript console issue in safari

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have native app and I am getting the below error in iOS.

> The source list for Content Security Policy directive 'script-src' contains an invalid source: ''strict-dynamic''. It will be ignored.

I am getting this error when I am debugging the app from Safari. I am using Google Captcha.

One more thing, I did not see this error at my development machine. This issue is only happening at UAT and Production environment.

Can any one know, why this issue is occur only on UAT and PROD environment?

Is it related to the Google Captcha?

Comment: Safari does not support the `strict-dynamic` CSP directive. If you use it in your CSP then it will produce that error. Safari supports [version 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSP2/) of the standard.

Comment: I am not using safari. I am just debugging my mobile app using safari. because, I have the issue when I click on username text input and keyboard collapse automatically. I debugged with safari browser and when error is occured  after that keyboard is collapsed.

Note: when, I am debugging the mobile application which is pointing to my local machine then I am not getting any error.